# onClick parent getElementById.click(); not working in CHROME

Tags: iframe, google-chrome, click, onclick, getelementbyid

I've been trying my best to solve this problem but I really can't find what's wrong. I'm not really experienced with javascript so it's probably something basic I'm missing.

Right now, after I copied the code I found to allow browsers besides IE to register click(); it works perfectly in every browser except for **Chrome**. I tested IE, FF, Safari, and Opera, they're all working.

My setup is that I have an iframe with buttons in it that are supposed to activate a shadowbox gallery in the parent.

**My script in the main page (index.html) is:**

```
<head>

//shadowbox linking
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox/shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init();
</script>

//included based on what I found online to enable the click(); method to work in browsers besides IE)
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof HTMLElement!='undefined'&&!HTMLElement.prototype.click)
HTMLElement.prototype.click=function(){
var evt = this.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, this.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
this.dispatchEvent(evt); }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<a id="web1" href="http://www.google.com/" rel="shadowbox[gallery]"></a>
<a id="web2" href="http://www.yahoo.com/" rel="shadowbox[gallery]"></a>

<iframe src="frame.html">You can't see
iframes.</iframe>
</body>
```

**My link in the iframe (frame.html) is:**

```
<a href="#" onClick="parent.document.getElementById('web1').click();">Link1</a>
<a href="#" onClick="parent.document.getElementById('web2').click();">Link2</a>
```

I really hope someone can help me out =) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Oh it seems I've found the problem -_-

There is nothing wrong with the script, it works perfectly fine. Chrome just seems to have some security issues when the files are hosted locally. I uploaded the files online and everything works fine. =)

I hope this will help someone who happens to come across it, especially linking Shadowbox from an iframe as I came across quite a few posts about it.

Answer (score 0):

.click() is not supported (well) in Chrome. One way around it is to use jQuery. Convert `getElementById('web2').click()` to `$("#web2").click()`.